# Fix joint length in Box2D?

Tags: box2d

I'm having some difficulties with Box2D DistanceJoints, I'm trying to create a rope using DistanceJoints connecting some bodies together but the length of joints between bodies change due to weight of bodies, is there any way to prevent joint lengths from changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may encounter this problem in the future: I just changed my approach, I used some `Revolute Joint` to connect bodies together and mark all bodies as sensor so that they don't collide with each other (tell me if you any better way to avoid collision of the rope parts), and use boxes to fill the space between joints (previously it was Distance joints connecting circle shapes). Having density set to non-zero value the result looks like a real rope.

Comment: RevoluteJoints and DistanceJoints serve different purposes. Select the one that suits you. If you want to have non-oscillating/firm distances between objects, you can see my answer about DistanceJoints.

Comment: (Their difference is described here http://www.box2d.org/manual.html.)

Comment: I know that, but in my case a fixture and two revoluteJoints produces better results than a DistanceJoint;

Comment: No worries, +1 since this answer works for you.

Comment: For those who read this, set "collideConnect" to "false" in the joint definition avoids fixtures contact.

Answer (score 5):

DistanceJoints can be soft spring like joints, or rigid and firm joints depending on your choice of `frequencyHz` and `dampingRatio`.

Set `dampingRatio` to 1.0 for zero oscillations (i.e. inflexible distance).

You may need to set `frequencyHz` to 0 as well.

Comment: I tried changing damping ratio and/ir frequencyHz to any valu that i could imagine, including the onces you suggested but didn't help at all.

Comment: What are the masses of the two objects that are joined?

Comment: at first they were both 1 (due to default density of fixtures) but then tried changing density to zero (the masses were still 1 because objects were dynamic) and it was same as before, no changes.

Comment: So let me just confirm that `density` of both objects is set to 1. The mass of both dynamic objects is 1, and the `dampingRatio` of the DistanceJoint is 1, and the `frequencyHz` is 0. And in this configuration, your distance joint expands and contracts?

Comment: that's right, i can even post my code here if you like'

Comment: after undoing many changes to apply your solution, I found what made them to expand. It was because when I increased the node in my rope their fixtures get inside one another and that made the joints expand, just seting all the rope fixtures to sensors solved my problem, thank you for your advise.

Comment: again I made a mistake that only fixed the problem because i accidentaly lowered the gravity. after changing it back to normal it was just the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem, and what I've done was using DistanceJoint, with the **frequencyHz set to 60** (or more) and the **dampingRatio set to 0**.

Imagine your distanceJoint as a rubber thread.

- Higher frequencyHz makes thread more persistent.
- Lower dampingRatio make it sooner for the thread gain original length after being stretched.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with ropes in Box2D until I discovered that a joint's "strength" is proportional to the mass of the bodies it is connected to. The solution that worked for me was just to increase the density of the rope until it was strong enough to hold other objects up.